# Merge rows using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a input file which has large data in below pattern. some part of data is shown below:

```
Data1 
C
In;
CP
In;
D
In;
Q
Out;
Data2 
CP
In;
D
In;
Q
Out;
Data3 
CP
In;
CPN
In;
D
In;
QN
Out;
```

I want my output as

```
Data1(C,CP,D,Q)
In C;
In CP;
In D;
Out Q;
Data2 (CP,D,Q)
In CP;
In D;
Out Q;
Data3 (CP,CPN,D,QN)
In CP;
In CPN;
In D;
Out QN;
```

How can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:];]+" }
{ rec[++nf] = $1 }
$1 == "Out" {
    printf "%s(", rec[1]
    for (i=2; i<=nf; i+=2) {
        printf "%s%s", (i>2 ? "," : ""), rec[i]
    }
    print ")"

    for (i=2; i<=nf; i+=2) {
        print rec[i+1], rec[i] ";"
    }

    delete rec
    nf = 0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Data1(C,CP,D,Q)
In C;
In CP;
In D;
Out Q;
Data2(CP,D,Q)
In CP;
In D;
Out Q;
Data3(CP,CPN,D,QN)
In CP;
In CPN;
In D;
Out QN;
```

Comment: Sir can you please explain the code once

Comment: I think it's extremely straight forward so please take a look at the man page to try to understand it yourself and then let me know if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n";} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ "Data") print $i; else if ($i ~ "In;") print "In " $(i-1)";" ; else if ($i ~ "Out") print "Out " $(i-1)";"}'  a.txt
```

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: a.txt contains input data.... whats the output u get after executing ths

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY `Its not working` is the worst possible problem statement as it provides absolutely no information that'd let anyone try to come up with a fix. Imagine dropping your car off at a mechanic and just saying `Its not working` and walking away.

Comment: @SandeepKothari You should mention that requires an awk with an extension to allow multi-char RS, e.g. GNU awk. A POSIX awk would just use `\n` as the RS given `RS="\n\n"`.

Comment: @sandeepkothari the output which i am getting after executing is```data1 in "in" \nin in \nout "out"``` like this. Can you explain the logic you used.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
gawk '
    BEGIN { FS = "\n"; RS = ";\n" }
    function output() {
        print data ")"
        for (i=1; i<=c; i++) print inout[i]
        delete inout
        c=0
    }
    NF == 3 {
        if (NR > 1) output()
        data = $1 "(" $2
        inout[++c] = $3 " " $2 ";"
    }
    NF == 2 {
        data = data "," $1
        inout[++c] = $2 " " $1 ";"
    }
    END {output()}
' file
```

```
Data1 (C,CP,D,Q)
In C;
In CP;
In D;
Out Q;
Data2 (CP,D,Q)
In CP;
In D;
Out Q;
Data3 (CP,CPN,D,QN)
In CP;
In CPN;
In D;
Out QN;
```

Comment: You should mention that requires an awk with an extension to allow multi-char RS, e.g. GNU awk. A POSIX awk would just use `;` as the RS given `RS=";\n"`.

Comment: Sir @glenn can you once explain logic used for this

Comment: I think it's fairly straightforward. Do you have any specific questions? Do you understand all the ALLCAPS variables?

Comment: No what are ALLCAPS variables??

Comment: Do you know what `FS`, `RS`, `NF` are in awk? The existing learning resources [on the awk info page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/awk/info) will do a better job teaching you awk than I can in a comment.

Comment: What is inout here??

Comment: Just a variable name. It's an array that holds the "In" and "Out" lines for each Data

Answer (score 0):

Invoking `GNU sed` with extended regexp mode `-E`, we can print the ports and also their types as shown. For more info.
you can lookup the manpages (man sed)
or the Gnu sed manual (info sed)

```
$ sed -Ee '
  /\n/{
    /\n.*\n/{P;D;}
    p;$d;g
  }
  :loop
    $break;N
  /;(\n[^;]+){2}$/!bloop
  :reak
  h;s/;[^;]+$/;/
  s/\n[^\n;]+;//g
  s/\n/(/;y/\n/,/;s/$/)/p
  g;s/.*;\n//
  x;s/;[^;]+$/;/
  s/\n([^\n]+)(\n[^\n;]+)/\2 \1/g
  D
' file
```

**Results:**

```
Data1 (C,CP,D,Q)
In C;
In CP;
In D;
Out Q;
Data2 (CP,D,Q)
In CP;
In D;
Out Q;
Data3 (CP,CPN,D,QN)
In CP;
In CPN;
In D;
Out QN;
```